# Checking if record field is unique (DBTables.TBDEDataSet.Lookup method)

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I want to check if record value in field "number_field" is unique so I'm locating record with the same value in number_field. I use Lookup method because I'm editing record:

```
id := SomeTable.Lookup('DOCUMENT_NUMBER', CurrentDocNumber, 'ID');
```

Of course in some cases it will give me the current record ID. How can I skip editing record?

*Edit: I don't want to disable saving document with the same number to the database - I just want to inform the user that number he wrote is already on system and let him decide what to do*

*Edit2: I operate only in loaded data - no DB*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use a TQuery and check if you have the record in the DB:

`select count(*) from my_table where DOCUMENT_NUMBER=CurrentDocNumber`

**EDIT:** 
The same could be done with a TDataSet. you could either `select count` or `select *` to test if `RecordCount > 0`

**EDIT2:**
just to be fair:
note that if this is the case `I operate only in loaded data - no DB` (this was an update after you accepted my answer) then my solution wont work because records are not yet posted to the live DB. never the less, you **must** use this query if there are more then 1 client connected and writing to the DB.

Comment: Indeed `Where doc_nb =current_doc_nr and id <> cur_id` but I want to use memory dataset

Comment: then use a memory dataset. it's the same

Comment: Ok, but it will move the record pointer of the dataset I'm currently editing.

Comment: no it wont. you are using **another** TDataSet or TQuery. best is to create it at run time.

Comment: Ok so I can do `select from` another dataset?

Comment: yes. that's the idea. this way, you don`t change the state in your current Table and it remains in edit mode.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6424/discussion-between-justme-and-kobik)

Comment: @JustMe TxQuery component is a TDataSet descendant component that can be used to query one or more TDataSet descendant components using SQL statements. It is availabe from http://code.google.com/p/txquery

Answer (score 1):

It's a good practice to set the DOCUMENT_NUMBER field as unique at the database level, then an exception will be raise automatically during posting, which will disallow posting the record.  You can also catch the exception and re-raise with your own error, such as "Document number already exists" etc.

If you can't do this, then you'd have to create another table component, and beforepost locate the record in the secondary table, and if it exists, raise an exception.

Comment: The point is I don't want to disable saving document with the same number - I just want to inform the user that number he wrote is already on system and let him decide what to do

Comment: Then searching a secondary table would be best :)

Comment: Secondary table with deleted/filtered record id? But the table can be big

Comment: No, you just do a locate on the secondary table.. no need to filter, and make sure DOCUMENT_NUMBER has an index.